# 'Display name' for database mail not showing in the email - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014

And I have procedure that send emails but when the recipients receive the email the display name it's not what I configured it shows my email  .

Here is screenshot of mail account configuration:

[image]

And here you can see the emails that have been sent all with account_id =1 and profile_id = 1 which is in the previews screenshot.

[image]

And this is a email sample , you can see the sender name which is my problem why it is not " Property Pricing System" ?

[image]

How to solve this ?

Comment: can you show some sample email

Comment: @thegameiswar question updated

Comment: Can you translate what the display name is?

Comment: @scsimon it's the sender name in Arabic which is me, my question why it's not like what I configured

Comment: Not sure. Is that the only email profile?

Comment: @scsimon yes only this profile (PPS)

Comment: Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

The display name override is being prevented by security settings on your SMTP server.  The server is looking up the name associated with that email account on your domain and using that.  You can change the SMTP security settings to allow overrides and it should use the display name you provide.

If you do not have the ability to access the security settings, a workaround that might work is to try entering an email address that is not valid on the domain, then it will not have a display name to use and will use your display name provided.  You can then add a valid reply to email if you need the receiver to respond.